# Duvida em filas

Tags: python

Entao pessoal, estou com duvida em dois algoritimos de fila, e gostaria de um auxilio. A primeira duvida,

```
From collections import Deque
class Fila:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fila = deque()  # atributo fila é um objeto do tipo deque

    def insere(self, novo):
        self.fila.append(novo)  # uso append para inserir no final

    def remove(self):
        return self.fila.popleft()  # popleft remove da esquerda (início)

    def tamanho(self):
        return len(self.fila)  # usa len para calcular tamanho da fila

    def vazia(self):
        if len(self.fila) == 0:
            return True
        return False

    def preferencial(self,novo):
        self.fila.appendleft(novo)
```

e então temos uma função que recebe uma fila como parametro e retorna uma lista com todos os itens removidos

```
def remove_todos(fila):
    lista = []
    fila = Fila()
    while fila.vazia() == False:
        fila.remove()
        lista.append(fila)
    return lista
```

e ela retorna uma lista vazia em vez dos itens da fila.

A segunda questão é a fila de um banco onde só um caixa funciona, e a cada dois clientes preferenciais, um cliente não preferencial será atendido.

```
def fila_banco(pessoas):
    fila = Fila()
    lista = []
    for x in pessoas:
        if x[1] >= 60:
            fila.preferencial(x[0])
            lista.append(x[0])
        else:
            fila.insere(x[0])
            lista.append(x[0])
    return lista

fila_banco([ ('Jorge', 22), ('Valter', 90), ('Alice', 88), ('Boris', 77) ])
```

que me retorna `['Jorge', 'Valter', 'Alice', 'Boris']`
oque deveria ser retornado `('Valter', 'Alice', 'Jorge', 'Boris')`

Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thiago tudo bom?

Então na sua primeira dúvida, seu mehodo remove() da classe Fila, ele retorna o primeiro elemento da fila, e quando você esta usando ele, apenas chama o metodo e não guada o seu retorno, tente fazer desta forma

```py
def remove_todos(fila):
    lista = []
    fila = Fila()
    while not fila.vazia():
        lista.append(fila.remove())
    return lista
```

E como não consigo testar código agora, não vou conseguir ver sua segunda pergunta agora, porem dei uma olhada aqui, e tente retornar a fila.fila.

```py
def fila_banco(pessoas):
    fila = Fila()
    lista = []
    for x in pessoas:
        if x[1] >= 60:
            fila.preferencial(x[0])
            lista.append(x[0])
        else:
            fila.insere(x[0])
            lista.append(x[0])
    return fila.fila

fila_banco([ ('Jorge', 22), ('Valter', 90), ('Alice', 88), ('Boris', 77) ])
```

Porque nas verificações você adicionar os maiores de 60 no inicio da fila, e também esta adicionando o mesmo na lista, porém, ao final, e quando você retorna essa lista ela vem na ordem errada de chamada. Rode estas mudanças e veja se funciona, quando puder dou uma olhada melhor. No entanto teste e comente o que aconteceu.

Código editado.

```py
def fila_banco(pessoas):
    lista = [x[0] for x in pessoas if x[1] >=60]
    nao_pref = [x[0] for x in pessoas if not x[1] >=60][::-1]
    start = 2

    while nao_pref:
        lenght_lista = len(lista)
        if lenght_lista >= start:
            lista.insert(start, nao_pref.pop())
            start += 3

        else:
            lista.insert(lenght_lista +1, nao_pref.pop())


    return fila
```

No caso eu criei uma lista na ordem que você deseja, você só precisara transformar em deque para poder chamar popleft. Se funcionar comenta aqui.

Comment: Opa  Robson, então eu fiz os testes aqui e a função remove_todos continua retornando uma lista vazia, já o fila_banco ele coloca o 'Jorge' no final, e o 'Boris' na frente do 'Valter' e da 'Alice', o retorno certo seria 'Valter', 'Alice', 'Jorge', 'Boris'

Comment: Fala Thiago tudo bem. Então cara peguei seu código, é fiz um algoritmo para esse problema, fiz alguns testes e me pareceu estar bem.vou editar a pergunta adicionando o código para vc poder usar e vê se funciona pra você.

Comment: Uma coisa que vi no seu código de remover todos, pelo visto ele deveria estar na classe Fila. Pois é um método referente a fila. Deveria ser um método nesse estilo ```python def remover_todos(self): lista = [] while not self.vazia(): lista.append(self.remover()) return lista